# How do I one-hot encode one column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to one-hot encode one column of a dataframe.

```
enc = OneHotEncoder()
minitable = enc.fit_transform(df["ids"])
```

But I'm getting

> DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17
>   and willraise ValueError in 0.19.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: does `minitable = enc.fit_transform(df[["ids"]])` work without warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ids':['a','b','c']})

print (df)
  ids
0   a
1   b
2   c

print (df.ids.str.get_dummies())
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
```

EDIT:

If input is column with `lists`, first cast to `str`, remove `[]` by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and call [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ids':[[0,4,5],[4,7,8],[5,1,2]]})

print(df)
         ids
0  [0, 4, 5]
1  [4, 7, 8]
2  [5, 1, 2]

print (df.ids.astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.get_dummies(', '))
   0  1  2  4  5  7  8
0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1
2  0  1  1  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: I would need to convert to string. Can it be done with integers and no casting?

Comment: Is problem use `print (df.ids.str.get_dummies().astype(str))` ?

Comment: the code above won't work when ids is a list of integers

Comment: Though this is all over StackOverflow, `get_dummies` isn't the best practice to perform encoding, as it doesn't keep the memory of the encoding itself on unseen data. Different data may be encoded in the same way, which defies the purpose of encoding in the first place.