# Converting a Pandas Dataframe column into one hot labels

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a pandas dataframe similar to this:

```
  Col1   ABC
0  XYZ    A
1  XYZ    B
2  XYZ    C
```

By using the pandas `get_dummies()` function on column ABC, I can get this:

```
  Col1   A   B   C
0  XYZ   1   0   0
1  XYZ   0   1   0
2  XYZ   0   0   1
```

While I need something like this, where the ABC column has a `list / array` datatype:

```
  Col1    ABC
0  XYZ    [1,0,0]
1  XYZ    [0,1,0]
2  XYZ    [0,0,1]
```

I tried using the `get_dummies` function and then combining all the columns into the column which I wanted. I found lot of answers explaining how to combine multiple columns as strings, like this: [Combine two columns of text in dataframe in pandas/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python). But I cannot figure out a way to combine them as a list.

This question introduced the idea of using sklearn's `OneHotEncoder`, but I couldn't get it to work. [How do I one-hot encode one column of a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185675/how-do-i-one-hot-encode-one-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

One more thing: All the answers I came across had solutions where the column names had to be manually typed while combining them. Is there a way to use `Dataframe.iloc()` or splicing mechanism to combine columns into a list?

Comment: "where the ABC column has a list / array datatype:" why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine columns in a Pandas DataFrame to a column of lists in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145148/combine-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-column-of-lists-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example of using [sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html):

```
In [361]: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

In [362]: lb = LabelBinarizer()

In [363]: df['new'] = lb.fit_transform(df['ABC']).tolist()

In [364]: df
Out[364]:
  Col1 ABC        new
0  XYZ   A  [1, 0, 0]
1  XYZ   B  [0, 1, 0]
2  XYZ   C  [0, 0, 1]
```

Pandas alternative:

```
In [370]: df['new'] = df['ABC'].str.get_dummies().values.tolist()

In [371]: df
Out[371]:
  Col1 ABC        new
0  XYZ   A  [1, 0, 0]
1  XYZ   B  [0, 1, 0]
2  XYZ   C  [0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: After getting the column of lists, I was able to convert list to array using:  `df['new'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))` . Is there a direct way to get array?

Comment: @Nir_J, i don't know how to assign Numpy 2D array to a single Pandas column directly. Pandas will think that we are assigning multiple columns... Actually that's why i used `.tolist()`

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `tolist()`:

```
df['ABC'] = pd.get_dummies(df.ABC).values.tolist()

  Col1        ABC
0  XYZ  [1, 0, 0]
1  XYZ  [0, 1, 0]
2  XYZ  [0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: This is the way I will do :-) Nice one ~

Answer (score 2):

If you have a pd.DataFrame like this:

```
>>> df
  Col1  A  B  C
0  XYZ  1  0  0
1  XYZ  0  1  0
2  XYZ  0  0  1
```

You can always do something like this:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda s: list(s[1:]), axis=1)
0    [1, 0, 0]
1    [0, 1, 0]
2    [0, 0, 1]
dtype: object
```

Note, this is essentially a for-loop on the rows. Note, columns do *not* have `list` data-types, they must be `object`, which will make your data-frame operations not able to take advantage of the speed benefits of `numpy`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the disadvantage of list. I wanted to be able to use just that one column as label to train the model. Will this solution be able to take speed benefits of numpy?

Comment: @Nir_J no. I'm not sure models in `sklearn` will accept a column of `list` objects anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a data-frame `df` with categorical column `ABC` then you could use to create a new column of one-hot vectors

```
df['new_column'] = list(pandas.get_dummies(df['AB]).get_values())
```